# UIImageView only shown when UITableViewCell is selected

Tags: ios, ipad, uitableview, uiimageview

I created a custom UITableViewCell and added 13 UIImageViews to it.  In my cellForRowAtIndexPath method, I set the image for each image view (if there is a photo available), however when the view loads none of the table cells are displaying the photos that are inside of them.  However, when I select a cell, all of the images load.  When I then select another cell, the images from the previous cell go away and the images of the cell I just selected show up.  Below is my cellForRowIndexPath method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *tableCell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"photoSessionCell"];
    PhotoSessionCell * cell = (PhotoSessionCell*) tableCell;
    NSMutableArray *photos = [[self dataSource] objectAtIndex:[indexPath indexAtPosition:1]]; 

    for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
        if (i < [photos count]) {
            UIImage * currImage = [photos objectAtIndex:i];
            switch (i) {
                case 0:
                    [[cell image1] setImage:currImage];
                    break;
                case 1:
                    [[cell image2] setImage:currImage];
                    break;
                case 2:
                    [[cell image3] setImage:currImage];
                    break;
                case 3:
                    [[cell image4] setImage:currImage];
                    break;
                case 4:
                    [[cell image5] setImage:currImage];
                    break;
                case 5:
                    [[cell image6] setImage:currImage];
                    break;
                case 6:
                    [[cell image7] setImage:currImage];
                    break;
                case 7:
                    [[cell image8] setImage:currImage];
                    break;
                case 8:
                    [[cell image9] setImage:currImage];
                    break;
                case 9:
                    [[cell image10] setImage:currImage];
                    break;
                case 10:
                    [[cell image11] setImage:currImage];
                    break;
                case 11:
                    [[cell image12] setImage:currImage];
                    break;
                default:
                    [[cell image13] setImage:currImage];
                    break;
            }
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    NSDate* date = [[self dates] objectAtIndex:[indexPath indexAtPosition:0]];
    NSDateFormatter * format  = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [format setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];
    [[cell textLabel] setText:[format stringFromDate:date]];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: why are you doing [cell imageX] setImage... Wouldn't you want to just set the image on 'cell' and not worry about the imageX?

Comment: What are you doing if `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` returns nil? Generally you try to dequeue, and if it's unable to dequeue (because there are none to dequeue, for example), you create a cell. Dequeue is an optimization for not creating new ones if you have old ones that can be recycled (e.g., because they've scrolled out of view), but it's not a replacement for creating cells. Where is your code for creating the cell with the 13 imageviews in the first place?

Comment: I'm setting the specific image since it affects positioning.

Comment: As for the dequeue, I created an instance in my storyboard file.  Dequeue is not returning nil.  The imageviews are hooked up in my storyboard.

Comment: I would try doing it just as a general 'setImage' and see if its something in your imageX code that is causing them to not display correctly. The rest of this code looks like it should be working correctly.

Comment: If you don't **setText** what happens?

Comment: @heckman each imageX is an actual uiimageview in the cell, so just setImage will not work.

Comment: @WarifAkhandRishi that worked!  Although now I need to figure out how to get the text and the photos both to display.

Comment: "textLabel" is the name of the default tableview cell text label field. Are you using the same name for the UILabel in your custom cell? I put my own UILabel on my custom cell in my storyboard, linked it to a UILabel property in my custom cell class that uses a different name (in my case, label1) and it works fine.